# How do I add symlinks of submodules in project

Tags: git, git-submodules, symlink, githooks, repo

Hi All is there a way to create symlinks from submodules .
Meaning If I have RepoA and RepoB.

RepoB is a git submodule of RepoA .
with normal git submodule I can achieve this repo structure .

```
RepoA
|______RepoB
|_folder1
|_folder2
|_folder3
```

Now I want to symlink files from RepoB into another folder in repoA ,so
to achieve this repo structure

```
RepoA
|______RepoB
|______folder1
|        |_(symlink files from RepoB)   
|
|______folder2
|         |_(symlink files from RepoB) 
| 
|______folder3
         |_(symlink files from RepoB)
```

To add to the complexity its not only repoB there are multiple of other repos to symlink from .

This was achievable before with [repo-git linkfile](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/docs/manifest-format.md#Element-linkfile) ,but we are changing tools in the company but its a requirement to keep the repo structures the same .

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "symlink" ? if you mean filesystem symlinks : git can store symlinks as part of the repo.

Comment: I know that these symlinks will be recreated correctly when checked out on a linux system, I'm not familiar with the issues you could get (if any) on a Windows system.

Comment: yes I need it file system symlinks , but not from the same repo ,. from git submodule

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- have a `setup.sh` script in `RepoA` which sets up the given symlinks,
- or have a `setup.sh [path/to/repoB]` in each of `folder1/2/3`

My suggestion would come together with `.gitignore` rules in each of `folder1/2/3` to not version these symlinks, and the requirement, for each developer, to call those scripts to correctly set up the project on their machine (and a similar action when building your project or deploying to production)

Comment: Is there a way to run these scripts automatically with every clone/pull of repo ?